# DbContext, connect Web Service instead database

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying connect to WebService by using EF.

So, I was override SaveChanges and doing add/update/delete operations with it.
My problem is, when i define my model into dbcontext class like that;

```
public DbSet<ModelAdlar> Adlar { get; set; }
```

But, I don't know how to convert data which i take from web service to DbSet.
Web service sending list as array ModelAdlar[] but, it was defined as DbSet. How i can manage that datasource or convert array to dbset?

I tried

```
public DbSet<ModelAdlar> Adlar { get
{
    var sr = new KontrolService.UserServiceClient();
    return (DbSet<ModelAdlar>)sr.Veriler(Ortak.up[0], Ortak.up[1]);// error: this line says can't convert array to dbset.
}
set {

} }
```

Comment: EF is an ORM for connecting to a database, not a web service. DbSets manage retrieval as well as addition/delete, change tracking, etc. Wrappers for web services should simply return IEnumerable. If you want to coordinate database updates (controlled by EF) with web service updates then consider wiring up an observer to the DbContext which will communicate with the web service based on DB operations. (And wrap all within a transaction if fault rollbacks are needed.)

Comment: Yes, i was used for direct connection to DB. But, now want to change and since i dont need extra sql commands with parameters, just need ToList, Add, Remove, Update only. I'm trying to find where select command executing, also tried inherit DbSet class. but never enters inside

Comment: EF is not designed for this purpose. You should add service reference to your projoect in visual studio and use it this way.